# Restarting rsync

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync to transfer some files using the command

```
rsync -acv --progress ./d-planetr ./c3-remotsn/
```

Suppose I stop a transfer and restart it again, will I be ensured that all file transfers completed successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but painfully slowly. Remove the `-c` flag so they rsync doesn't have to recalculate checksums for all previously copied files

Comment: Would checksums not be superior?  What ensures that the transfer was complete?

Comment: Without the `-c` option, `rsync` compared source and destination files using modification time and size. Most most cases this is sufficient to say whether a file has been changed or not. The transfer is complete when the source and destination match using either method.

Comment: Only use `-c` if you think the files already copied might have been mangled without changing their timestamp or size.  This is typically very unlikely.  Without `-c`, if size or date don't match, rsync will calculate partial checksums anyway to figure out if the whole file needs to be transferred or just pieces.  If you expect interruptions, you should also include the `--partial` option so that incomplete files are not deleted and can be resumed as well.

Comment: @user10489 in this case no that's not quite right. For a local to local copy, if there is any difference in size the destination will simply be deleted and the copy taken afresh. Partial is also irrelevant in this case

Comment: MIssed that this was local to local.  The rules (and default options) are certainly different for that.